# Melhorar performance - Parallel Foreach pegando nós XML C#/.NET

Tags: c#, .net, desempenho, foreach, paralelismo

Eu gostaria de melhorar a performance desse código a seguir:

```
private static void AddXmlReportNfe(XmlNode xml, ConcurrentBag<XmlReport> listReport)
{
    var xmlKey = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infProt/chNFe")?.InnerText;

    if (listReport.Any(i => i.ChNFe == xmlKey))
        return;

    var products = xml.SelectNodes("//infNFe/det");
    if (products != null)
    {
        Parallel.ForEach(products.Cast<XmlNode>(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 }, product =>
        {
            var cpfEmit = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/emit/CPF")?.InnerText;
            var cnpjEmit = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/emit/CNPJ")?.InnerText;
            var rzEmit = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/emit/xNome")?.InnerText;
            var ieEmit = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/emit/IE")?.InnerText;
            var ufEmit = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/emit/enderEmit/UF")?.InnerText;

            var cpfDest = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/dest/CPF")?.InnerText;
            var cnpjDest = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/dest/CNPJ")?.InnerText;
            var rzDest = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/dest/xNome")?.InnerText;
            var ieDest = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/dest/IE")?.InnerText;
            var ufDest = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/dest/enderDest/UF")?.InnerText;

            var nNF = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/ide/nNF")?.InnerText;
            var serie = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/ide/serie")?.InnerText;
            var tpNf = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/ide/tpNf")?.InnerText == "0" ? "Entrada" : "Saída";
            var dhEmiStr = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/ide/dhEmi")?.InnerText;
            var finNfe = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/ide/finNFe")?.InnerText;
            var infCpl = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/infAdic/infCpl")?.InnerText;
            var infAdFisco = xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/infAdic/infAdFisco")?.InnerText;

            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/total/ICMSTot/vPIS")?.InnerText, out var vPis);
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/total/ICMSTot/vCOFINS")?.InnerText, out var vCofins);
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/total/ICMSTot/vIPI")?.InnerText, out var vIpi);
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/total/ICMSTot/vICMS")?.InnerText, out var vIcmsTot);
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/total/ICMSTot/vNF")?.InnerText, out var vNf);

            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/total/ICMSTot/vFrete")?.InnerText, out var vFrete);
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(xml.SelectSingleNode("//infNFe/total/ICMSTot/vOutro")?.InnerText, out var vOutro);

            var xProd = product.SelectSingleNode(".//prod/xProd")?.InnerText;
            var qCom = product.SelectSingleNode(".//prod/qCom")?.InnerText;
            var uCom = product.SelectSingleNode(".//prod/uCom")?.InnerText;
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(product.SelectSingleNode(".//prod/vDesc")?.InnerText, out var vDesc);
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(product.SelectSingleNode(".//prod/vUnCom")?.InnerText, out var vUnCom);
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(product.SelectSingleNode(".//prod/vProd")?.InnerText, out var vProd);
            var cfop = product.SelectSingleNode(".//prod/CFOP")?.InnerText;
            var cest = product.SelectSingleNode(".//prod/CEST")?.InnerText;
            long.TryParse(product.SelectSingleNode(".//prod/NCM")?.InnerText, out var ncm);

            var pisAliqCst = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/PIS/PISAliq/CST")?.InnerText;
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/PIS/PISAliq/vBC")?.InnerText, out var pisAliqVBc);
            var pisAliqPPis = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/PIS/PISAliq/pPIS")?.InnerText;
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/PIS/PISAliq/vPIS")?.InnerText, out var pisAliqVPis);
            var pisCst = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/PIS/PISNT/CST")?.InnerText;

            var cofinsCst = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/COFINS/COFINSNT/CST")?.InnerText;

            var cofinsAliqCst = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/COFINS/COFINSAliq/CST")?.InnerText;
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/COFINS/COFINSAliq/vBC")?.InnerText, out var cofinsAliqVBc);
            var cofinsAliqPCofins = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/COFINS/COFINSAliq/pCOFINS")?.InnerText;
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/COFINS/COFINSAliq/vCOFINS")?.InnerText, out var cofinsAliqVCofins);

            var icmsOrig = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/ICMS/orig")?.InnerText;
            var icmsCst = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/ICMS/CST")?.InnerText;
            var icmsModBc = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/ICMS/modBC")?.InnerText;
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/ICMS/vBC")?.InnerText, out var icmsVBc);
            var icmsPIcms = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/ICMS/pICMS")?.InnerText;
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/ICMS/vICMS")?.InnerText, out var icmsVIcms);
            var icmsModBcSt = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/ICMS/modBCST")?.InnerText;
            var icmsPImcsSt = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/ICMS/pICMSST")?.InnerText;
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/ICMS/vICMSST")?.InnerText, out var icmsVIcmsSt);
            var icmsPMvaSt = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/ICMS/pMVAST")?.InnerText;
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/ICMS/vBCST")?.InnerText, out var icmsVBcSt);
            var icmsCsosn = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/ICMS/CSOSN")?.InnerText;

            var ipiTribCst = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/IPI/IPITrib/CST")?.InnerText;
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/IPI/IPITrib/vBC")?.InnerText, out var ipiTribVbc);
            var ipiTribPipi = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/IPI/IPITrib/pIPI")?.InnerText;
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/IPI/IPITrib/vIPI")?.InnerText, out var ipiTribVipi);
            var ipiNtCst = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/IPI/IPINT/CST")?.InnerText;
            DoubleTryParseCurrencyEnUs(product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/IPI/IPINT/vBC")?.InnerText, out var ipiNtVbc);
            var ipiNtPipi = product.SelectSingleNode(".//imposto/IPI/IPINT/pIPI")?.InnerText;

            var status = xml.SelectSingleNode("//siegInfo/xMotivo")?.InnerText;

            DateTime? dhEmi = null;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dhEmiStr))
                dhEmi = DateTime.Parse(dhEmiStr);

            var report = new XmlReport
            {
                NumNFe = nNF,
                SerieNFe = serie,
                TpNf = tpNf,
                CnpjEmit = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cpfEmit) ? cnpjEmit : cpfEmit,
                CnpjDest = string.IsNullOrEmpty(cpfDest) ? cnpjDest : cpfDest,
                RzEmit = rzEmit,
                RzDest = rzDest,
                IEEmit = ieEmit,
                IEDest = ieDest,
                UFEmit = ufEmit,
                UFDest = ufDest,
                FinNFe = finNfe,
                X_Prod = xProd,
                Q_Com = qCom,
                U_Com = uCom,
                V_Prod = vProd,
                CFOP = cfop,
                NCM = ncm,
                Inf_Cpl = infCpl,
                Inf_Ad_Fisco = infAdFisco,
                V_Frete = vFrete,
                V_Outro = vOutro,
                PIS_NT_CST = pisCst,
                COFINS_NT_CST = cofinsCst,
                ICM_Stot_V_PIS = vPis,
                ICM_Stot_V_COFINS = vCofins,
                ICM_Stot_V_IPI = vIpi,
                ICM_Stot_V_ICMS = vIcmsTot,
                ICM_Stot_VNF = vNf,
                V_Un_Com = vUnCom,
                V_Desc = vDesc,
                PIS_Aliq_CST = pisAliqCst,
                PIS_Aliq_V_BC = pisAliqVBc,
                PIS_Aliq_P_PIS = pisAliqPPis,
                PIS_Aliq_V_PIS = pisAliqVPis,
                COFINS_Aliq_CST = cofinsAliqCst,
                COFINS_Aliq_V_BC = cofinsAliqVBc,
                COFINS_Aliq_P_COFINS = cofinsAliqPCofins,
                COFINS_Aliq_V_COFINS = cofinsAliqVCofins,
                CEST = cest,
                IMCS_Orig = icmsOrig,
                IMCS_CST = icmsCst,
                IMCS_Mod_BC = icmsModBc,
                IMCS_V_BC = icmsVBc,
                IMCS_P_ICMS = icmsPIcms,
                IMCS_V_ICMS = icmsVIcms,
                IMCS_Mod_BC_ST = icmsModBcSt,
                IMCS_P_ICMS_ST = icmsPImcsSt,
                IMCS_V_ICMS_ST = icmsVIcmsSt,
                IMCS_P_MVA_ST = icmsPMvaSt,
                IMCS_V_BC_ST = icmsVBcSt,
                IMCS_CSOSN = icmsCsosn,
                IPI_Trib_CST = ipiTribCst,
                IPI_Trib_V_BC = ipiTribVbc,
                IPI_Trib_P_IPI = ipiTribPipi,
                IPI_Trib_V_IPI = ipiTribVipi,
                IPI_NT_CST = ipiNtCst,
                IPI_NT_V_BC = ipiNtVbc,
                IPI_NT_P_IPI = ipiNtPipi,
                DhEmi = dhEmi,
                ChNFe = xmlKey,
                Status = status
            };
            listReport.Add(report);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Deve colocar um link para o documento XML que está a ler